# How to add a new Key value pair in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects as follows

```
[
  {
    name: "ABC",
    grade: 2
  },
  {
    name: "DEF",
    grade: 3
  },
  .....
]
```

Now I want to add an extra key value pair to each object in the array so that array becomes as follows

```
[
  {
    name: "ABC",
    grade: 2,
    id: 23
  },
  {
    name: "DEF",
    grade: 3,
    id: 33
  },
  .....
]
```

How can it be done in Node.js??

Comment: I think you need to have a way to view cookies reactively. Whenever cookie changes, you want to show authorized page or login page accordingly. cookee changes are not reactive inherently . It's better to keep a check at the place where you are making api calls. Whenever api call fails you can redirect to login page.

Comment: Maybe you can ue [react-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie/#readme) useCookie hook.

Comment: You should pass empty array as the useEffect dependencies array. Also, you need to wrap the cookie checking part with a function and should call it in useEffect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `map` is the best way.

Try this:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name: "ABC",
    grade: 2
  },
  {
    name: "DEF",
    grade: 3
  },
]

var newArr = arr.map(obj =>({ ...obj, id: obj.grade*10+3}))

console.log(newArr)
```

But it's not clear how you want to set the `id` value, `grade * 10 + 3`?

Answer (score 1):

```
const array = [...]
array.forEach(x =>{
 x.id = 23
})
```

Or if you want to do in an immutable way:

```
const array = [...]
const newArray = array.map(x =>({
 ...x,
 id: 23
}))
```